# PHP path string turns into '\/'

Tags: php

I have a mySqli table with image paths such as:

```
assets/images/profile_pics/00fa5fa61df8a9e22e3444c
```

Upon reading it with PHP like so:

```
<?php

require 'config/config.php';

$st=$con->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
$st->execute();
$rs=$st->get_result();
$arr=array();
while($row=$rs->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($arr, $row);
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

?>

The path turns into:

```
assets\/images\/2_pics\/00fa5fa61df8a9e22e3444c285bed8d38n.jpeg
```

Each / turns into /

I tried a few things such as:

```
$row['imageUrl'] = urldecode($row['imageUrl']);
$row['imageUrl'] = str_replace('\/', '/',$row['imageUrl']);
```

But it seems like / cannot be found in the string for some reason. What can I do to keep the original path without adding extra slashes?

Comment: Of course, because you `json_encode()` it. Use `json_decode()` and you get the string back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to encode that array into JSON, but don't want the slashes, you should pass `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` flag as a second parameter to `json_encode`:

```
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $path = 'assets\/images\/2_pics\/00fa5fa61df8a9e22e3444c285bed8d38n.jpeg';
```

$original_path =   stripslashes("assets/images/2_pics/00fa5fa61df8a9e22e3444c285bed8d38n.jpeg");

Now Your $original_path will be as your original path which is ->

```
assets/images/2_pics/00fa5fa61df8a9e22e3444c285bed8d38n.jpeg
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems like the json encoding itself adds the slashes